# Not sorting all lines in table when using button but works from ribbon

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort a large table based on the second column. When I run the code from the vba ribbon or step through the function it works but when I use a button it doesnt work correctly. I tried adding a application.wait before the apply statement but that didnt work either because the button doesnt make the code wait. I have it hard coded to a size larger than the table but I used to have the second range value as topLeft.End(xlToRight).End(xlDown) and it still didn't work. This is my first post so let me know if I need to clarify anything.  Ill update the post if I find anything. See the code below (taken directly from a recorded macro).

```
   Range(topLeft, topLeft.Offset(40, 40)).Select
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range(topLeft.Offset(0, 1).Address), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange Range(topLeft, topLeft.Offset(40, 40))
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

Comment: Is the button on the same sheet as the data table?

Comment: When you say "it doesnt work correctly", what happens exactly? Also, is it possible that the button is assigned to a different macro?

Comment: Using `Active...`, `Select`, `Activate` is generally a bad idea. Refer to your workbook/worksheet/range specifically.

Comment: Please share the code that sets `topLeft`. Is your data contiguous (no empty rows or columns) and is it followed by an empty row and column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimize your code:

```
    Set myRange = topLeft.CurrentRegion ' define the range here
    With ActiveSheet.Sort ' ActiveSheet is the correct object to use with the onsheet button
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=myRange.Columns(2) _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange myRange
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

This code is correct and performed synchronously. If it counteracts something, find the reason outside this code.
[image]